# Navigating Tabs in a Web Page Using JAWS Screen Reader

Tags: tabs, jaws-screen-reader

What keystrokes should one use to navigate tabs on a web page using JAWS Screen Reader? I'm talking about tabs within a web page, not separate web pages opened in different tabs. Such tabs usually appear in the middle of web pages.

What I want to know is how to navigate from one tab to its associated content area. Also, once I'm done reading the tab's content, I want to go back to tab titles, switch to another tab, and then read that second tab content.

I help to build websites that are accessible to screen reader users. An answer to this question would allow us to test what we develop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within tabs user will expect to use left/right arrow to navigate between tabs.
1. User press tab key to focus to the tab strip; the first tab item gets focus.
2. Then will use left/right arrow to jump between tabs.
3. Pressing tab key again, will move the focus out of the tab strip to the next focusable element.
Complete aria guidelines for tabpanel is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#tabpanel

Answer (score 0):

Once a tab control has focus, use the apostrophe key to navigate through tabs.